# How to pass formData using Dropzone in Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, dropzone

I am using dropzone to upload a CSV file. The upload part is working and is doing the POST to the url in the config.

How do I pass additional parameter so that I can access it in my controller? In this case, I want to pass `account_id` to the controller.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="vertical-container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="stretch" fxFlex="50%">
          <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
            <div class="box-title">Dropzone</div>

            <select class="form-control input-sm mb-md" [(ngModel)]="account_id" name="account_id">
              <option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [ngValue]="account.id">{{account.name}}</option>
            </select>

            <div class="content-container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="stretch" fxFlex="auto">
              <dropzone class="dropzone-container" [config]="config" [disabled]="disabled" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start strech" fxFlex="auto" [message]="'Click or drag transaction file here to upload'" (init)="onUploadInit($event)" (error)="onUploadError($event)" (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)"></dropzone>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Here is the typescript (onUploadSuccess function):

```
public onUploadSuccess(args: any): void {       
    console.log('onUploadSuccess:', args);    
  }
```

Here is the controller in C#:

```
public void Post(IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = HttpContext.Request.Form;

                var files = request.Files;

                if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                string filePath = Path.Combine("D:", "Projects", "Finance", "Uploads", files[0].FileName);

                using (var targetStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                {
                    files[0].CopyTo(targetStream);
                }

                //Need to get the account_id here!
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //return new JsonResult(new { status = "500", error = "Internal Server Error", message = ex.Message })
                //{
                //    StatusCode = 500
                //};
            }
        }
```

When the file gets uploaded it will console log the message and hit the url in config. How do I pass account_id, so I can access that in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to it.

HTML (added sending event to dropzone):

```
       <div class="vertical-container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="stretch" fxFlex="50%">
          <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
            <div class="box-title">Dropzone</div>

            <select class="form-control input-sm mb-md" [(ngModel)]="account_id" name="account_id">
              <option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [ngValue]="account.id">{{account.name}}</option>
            </select>

            <div class="content-container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="stretch" fxFlex="auto">
              <dropzone class="dropzone-container" [config]="config" [disabled]="disabled" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start strech" fxFlex="auto" [message]="'Click or drag transaction file here to upload'" (init)="onUploadInit($event)" (error)="onUploadError($event)" (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)" (sending)="onSending($event)"></dropzone>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Typescript:

```
  public onSending(args: any): void {
    console.log('onSending', args);
    args[2].append("account_id", this.account_id);
  }
```

Server side (C#):

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public void Post(IFormFile file) //can also add int account_id here
        {
            try
            {
                var request = HttpContext.Request.Form;

                int accountId;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request["account_id"]))
                {
                    int.TryParse(request["account_id"], out accountId);
                }

                var files = request.Files;

                if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                string filePath = Path.Combine("D:", "Projects", "Finance", "Uploads", files[0].FileName);

                using (var targetStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                {
                    files[0].CopyTo(targetStream);
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               //catch the exception here
            }
        }
```

You can get the `account_id` from `request["account_id"]`

OR

you can have `account_id` as a parameter. Like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public void Post(int account_id, IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
              //account_id will be whatever is sent from client
            }
            catch()
            {
               //catch exception here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If the data is static or pre-existed and you are 100% sure about the data then you can pass in config inside params like this.

```
public config: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
    url: '/upload',
    cancelReset: null,
    clickable: true,
    maxFiles: 1,
    autoReset: null,
    errorReset: null,
    params: {
      "account_id": 123
 }
}
```

but if you are getting value on runtime from the user and assigning it to config then it will be undefined or will always send the initial value as config gets initialized on component init. For passing dynamic data you can make use of the following method.

```
onSending($event) {
// here you can assign data to config.
   this.config.params = {account_id: this.account_id };
//Also you can send the account_id in url.
    this.config.url = this.baseUrl + `/${this.accountId || 0}/account`;

  }
```

and the following is the code for accepting account id from URL on the API side.

```
  [HttpPost("{accountId}/account")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(int accountId, IFormFile file)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: This is giving me 404 Not Found on the POST